# Rewrite url: somesite.com/product.php?pid=1 to somesite.com/products/1

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite this url
**www.somesite.com/product.php?pid=1**
to
**www.somesite.com/products/1**

I use these codes in htaccess but i receive 404 error in my browser

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/product\.php  /products/%1?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)$ products.php?pid=$1
```